# T-SQLpad leading zeros in string for values between "." character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert numbers to 3 decimal places for each number between the character ".".  For example:

```
1.1.5.2 -> 001.001.005.002
1.2 -> 001.002
4.0 -> 004.000
4.3 ->004.003
4.10 -> 004.010
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT ItemNo
FROM EstAsmTemp
```

Comment: three characters is the max for each value between character .

Comment: Yuck. Why are you storing multiple delimited values in a single interesection? This violates 1NF and causes mountains of pain. You will have to first parse this into each element, then convert each data point to what you want and finally shove it all back into a single column again. This is just the wrong approach for storing data.

Comment: its a itemno in an engineering bill of materials.  it needs to be in this format for conversion into another system.

Comment: This is a task better suited for the presentation layer then for sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention the number of '.' separator a column can have. I assume, the max is 4 and the solution is below.

```
SELECT STUFF(ISNULL('.' + RIGHT('000' + PARSENAME(STRVALUE,4),4),'') + ISNULL('.' + RIGHT('000' + PARSENAME(STRVALUE,3),4) ,'') + ISNULL('.' + RIGHT('000' + PARSENAME(STRVALUE,2),4) ,'') + ISNULL('.' + RIGHT('000' + PARSENAME(STRVALUE,1),4),''),1,1,'')
FROM (VALUES('1.1.5.2'), ('1.2'), ('4.0'),('4.3'), ('4.10')) A (STRVALUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy once you understand all the steps:

1. Split the string into the individual data points.
2. Convert the parsed values into the format you want.
3. Shove the new values back into a delimited list.

Ideally you shouldn't store data with multiple datapoints in a single intersection like this but sometimes you just have no choice.

I am using the string splitter from Jeff Moden and the community at Sql Server Central which can be found here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/. There are plenty of other decent string splitters out there. Here are some excellent examples of other options. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings.

Make sure you understand this code before you use it in your production system because it will be you that gets the phone call at 3am asking for it to be fixed.

```
with something(SomeValue) as
(
    select '1.1.5.2' union all
    select '1.2' union all
    select '4.0' union all
    select '4.3' union all
    select '4.10'
)
, parsedValues as
(
    select SomeValue
        , right('000' + CAST(x.Item as varchar(3)), 3) as NewValue
        , x.ItemNumber as SortOrder
    from something s
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(SomeValue, '.') x
)

select SomeValue
    , STUFF((Select '.' + NewValue
            from parsedValues pv2
            where pv2.SomeValue = pv.SomeValue
            order by pv2.SortOrder
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as Details
from parsedValues pv
group by pv.SomeValue
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to change it in the presentation layer, per Zohar Peled's comment.